# match agains french characters

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to regex match a first character of the string against the following regex (idea is to ensure it is a valid French character)

```
/^[a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿæœ .-]*$/i
```

My attempt is

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(my_string, 1,1) ~* '/^[a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿæœ .-]/'
```

But it returns false. Could you please help me fixing the query?

Comment: `'^[a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿæœ .-]'` - remove `/` chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, regexps are defined with strings, and the `/` - that used as *regex delimiters* (that separate *action*, *pattern* and *flags*) in languages like Perl, PHP, JavaScript - are treated not as delimiters, but as part of the *pattern* itself.

Thus, you should use

```
'^[a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿæœ .-]'
```